# Webservice POST not displaying requested parameters using rest client in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have headers set as Accept application/json and content-type application/json for my POST webservice. Follwing are the requested parameters:

```
 { 
  "OccupantID": 162921,
  "BuildingID": 13294,
  "QuizID": 397,
  "Score": 3,
  "Result": "fail"
 }
```

routes.rb

```
  map.connect '', :controller => 'quiz_v2', :action => 'record_quiz_result', :conditions => { :method => :post }
```

When I try to see params in my controller's action

```
  def record_quiz_result
   p params
  end
 It returned just controller_name and action_name
```

I dont know what is happening here, May be I missed something.
Any Help

Answer (score 0):

```
Goto Headers => Custom Header
```

1.Content-Type as name and application/x-www-form-urlencoded as value and save it.

2.Now enter ur params in body which should be available and accessible through the params hash in rails

Hope it helps